# Undefined errors even though I included the correct library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting an undefined error on `strlen` and `strcpy` even though I included `<cstring>`. I'm using Visual Studio Community 17.

Here's what I done so far and none worked:

- `using namespace std`
- `std::strlen`
- `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`
- `#include <iostream>`

I'm going crazy over this error.

Here's my header file

```
#ifndef TEXT_H
#define TEXT_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Text
{
public:
 // Constructors and operator=
  Text(const char* charSeq = ""); 
  Text(const Text& other); // Copy constructor
  void operator = (const Text& other); // Assignment
  // Destructor
  ~Text();
  // Text operations
  int getLength() const; // # characters
  char operator [] (int n) const; // Subscript
  void clear(); // Clear string
  // Output the string structure -- used in testing/debugging
  void showStructure() const;
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  // In-lab operations
  // toUpper/toLower operations (Programming Exercise 2)
  Text toUpper() const; // Create upper-case copy
  Text toLower() const; // Create lower-case copy
  // Relational operations (Programming Exercise 3)
  bool operator == (const Text& other) const;
  bool operator < (const Text& other) const;
  bool operator > (const Text& other) const;
private:
    // Data members
    int bufferSize; // Size of the string buffer
    char* buffer; // Text buffer containing a null-terminated sequence of characters
    // Friends
    // Text input/output operations (In-lab Exercise 1)
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, Text& inputText);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Text& outputText);
};
#endif
```

[image]

Cpp file

```
#include "Text.h"
#include <cstring>

Text::Text(const char *charSeq) 
{
  bufferSize = strlen(charSeq) + 1;
  buffer = new char[bufferSize];
  strcpy(buffer, charSeq);
}
```

heres the compiler error `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(67,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v142 (Platform Toolset = 'v142') cannot be found. To build using the v142 build tools, please install v142 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".`

Comment: Have you tried to specify the namespace `std::` or `using namespace std;` as an alternative?

Comment: Yes I tired both of those and its the same error

Comment: Try to create a minimanistic application with just a main() function. We don't see what happens in your headers.

Comment: [`std::strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) and [`std::strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) are indeed declared in `<cstring>`, so if your compiler does not recognize them then it is messed up. That being said, you really should be using `std::string` instead of `char*`

Comment: Does your actual compiler complain?  Intellisense isn't perfect, and sometimes takes a while to update.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov okay so I made a new project folder and made a main() function and its works fine. It even shows up on the autocomplete thing, it doesn't do that on my other project. I included my header file in my post.

Comment: You have shown us an empty class definition in your header but you try to define the constructors in your CPP file. Be consistent. Or better create a minimalistic application without headers and class declarations.

Comment: @SanthoshAbraham I see no compiler error.  Compiler errors have the letter `C` followed by a 4 digit number in the Visual C++ world.  What you're showing us is some message from a tool, probably Intellisense, and **not** a compiler error.  Actually build your program and show us the compiler error that shows up in the compiler output window, if such an error is occurring.

Comment: You should not be using any of those anyway.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov sorry fixed

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is the compiler error MSB8020

Comment: The  error you show indicates you may not have the proper workload installed for C++ code. Run 'Visual Studio Installer' and check that you have the right workload selected. For example *Desktop development with C++*.  If you have *Universal Windows Platform development* selected, you need the optional component *C++ Universal Windows Platform tools* as well.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Yup I have all those installed, when I make a new project folder and a new .cpp file the problem doesn't happen, but idk why its not working with this project.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt strlen in the std namespace?

So it would be std::strlen()

For instance, this works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string oof = "oof";
    std::cout << std::strlen(oof.c_str()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you also included iostream?

Comment: Eliminate an IDE config issue. Open the "VS Developers Command Prompt" change to the directory with the source file, then compile with `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /EHsc /Fotest.obj /Fetest.exe /TP test.cpp` Unless there is something really wrong with your setup, it should compile to `test.exe` without warning. (type `cl /?` for a list of all compiler options)